# Chrome Extension sends unreadable data to python script

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, encoding, utf-8, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Chrome extensions and just built a popup that, when submitted via Javascript, sends info to a Python Script on GAE which works with the data. Now, everything works perfectly fine as long as I do not use special characters like Ä,Ö,Ü. When I do use these letters, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in     default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
return handler.dispatch()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~google.com:finaggintel/1.368063289009985228/main.py", line 115, in post
t.title = self.request.get('title').encode('utf-8')
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 175, in get
param_value = self.get_all(argument_name)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 212, in get_all
param_value = self.params.getall(argument_name)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1/webob/multidict.py", line 327, in getall
return map(self._decode_value, self.multi.getall(self._encode_key(key)))
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1/webob/multidict.py", line 301, in _decode_value
value = value.decode(self.encoding, self.errors)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

To be frank - I have no idea where to debug this issue. I tried utf-8 de- and encoding in Python (but again, this is new to me):

```
class News(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):     
    try: 
        user_job = joblist[user][0]
        user_pod = joblist[user][1]
    except KeyError:
        user_job = 'Guest'
        user_pod = 'Guest'

    link = self.request.get('link').encode('utf-8')

    if 'http' not in self.request.get('link'):
        link ='http://'+self.request.get('link')
    else:
        link = self.request.get('link')

    t = NewsBase(parent=news_key('finaggnews'))
    t.user = user
    t.date = datetime.now()
    t.text = self.request.get('text').encode('utf-8')
    t.title = self.request.get('title').encode('utf-8')
    t.link = link
    t.upvotes = []
    t.downvotes = []
    t.put()
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I even close to the issue? Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Included Traceback

Comment: include the stack trace and let us know where in the code you are getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

You have it back to front, you should be decoding the inboud data to a unicode representation.

e.g.

```
>>> x = "Ä"
>>> x.decode('utf-8')
u'\xc4'
>>> 
>>> y=x.decode('utf-8')
>>> print y
Ä
>>>
```

So for your line

```
t.title = self.request.get('title').encode('utf-8')
```

try

```
t.title = self.request.get('title').decode('utf-8')
```

However this assumes the data is needs to decoded from a utf-8 stream.

You should specify  `accept-charset="utf-8"` in the form (or on the client when posting) so that the correct encoding is defined rather than guessing and trying to decode.

For instance on windows the default encoding isn't utf-8 but latin_1 and trying to decode utf-8 from latin_1 wouldn't work.  The character the decode('utf-8') was failing on (0xdc) can be decoded if you use decode('latin_1')

Comment: Where is the data coming from, is it really utf-8 or Unicode.  Have you set accept-charset="utf-8"  in the form ?  0xdc seems like its latin_1.

Comment: The "accept-charset" part was new to me, but it just procudes a new error: """UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xdc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)""". Maybe this helps? BTW: I use the same processing and the exact same form on GAE (not Chrome extension) and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Nevermind - it works with the accept-charset, just forgot to take out the decodes! Thanks, can you edit your answer so I can accept it?